# Cant get drop down to show right for the menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

[image: Image description here]

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Beat Human Trafficking Blog</a>
```

This is menu list:

```
<div class="bs-example">
       <div class="dropdown">
         <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Action</a>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Another action</a>
         </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to put your anchor tag inside of the dropdown div:

```
<div class="bs-example">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropdownMenuLink">Beat Human Trafficking Blog</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Action</a>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Another action</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That fixed it for me. [Here](https://codepen.io/codeartistgirl/pen/wbbgLK) is the codepen if you would like the reference.

Comment: Thank you so much @codeartistgirl. how would I add the onlick function to go to the next page or would have to change the div.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking exactly. Do you want one of the href="#" to go to a specific page? If so, just change the "#" to your page link or anchor tag link.